# Loading ultisnips with NeoBundleLazy

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I've found that ultisnips is one of the slowest plugins to load at startup.

How do I use `NeoBundleLazy` to load ultisnips later, eg upon entering insert mode?

I've tried:

```
NeoBundleLazy 'SirVer/ultisnips', {
    \ 'autoload': {
    \   'insert': 1,
    \   },
    \ }
```

But get this error message on loading vim:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "*":
E117: Unknown function: UltiSnips#FileTypeChanged
```

Comment: You don't need lazy loading for well-behaving plugins.

Comment: Well behaved, slow loading plugins like NERTree seem to lazy load just fine.

Comment: Lazy loading won't always work as the plugin manager can never know what the plugin needs to be doing. Since vim already by default supports lazy loading (`:h autoload`), this is the way to go, and don't use the plugin manager for this. If a plugin does not support it, it should be fixed, don't depend on some plugin manager for this.